# Get Another Process' QueryPerformanceCounter()

Tags: c#

I'm trying to run QueryPerformanceCounter() function from a particular process and get its return value to my C# application. Since those two processes (my application and the application i'm trying to affect) are different, what kind of strategy should i follow?

Comment: What do you mean "the application I'm trying to affect"? `QueryPerformanceCounter` does not modify the process.

Comment: I'm trying to detect speedhacking attemps over a process. There are some hacking programs (i.e. cheat engine) which change speed of a particular process. Thus, I need to run this function in another process and get its return value to my own process to inspect values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QueryPerformanceCounter` is synchronized across all processes on a computer. You can just call it locally. That's the same value that the other process would have received.

**Update**: Okay, you're defending against cheaters. If they are hooking your process, then they are also going to hook your child processes, so spawning a helper process won't help much.

One thing you can do is correlate multiple timers. For example,

```
QueryPerformanceCounter(&liStart);
dwStart = GetTickCount();
GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&ftStart);
Sleep(1000);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&liStop);
dwStop = GetTickCount();
GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&ftStop);
```

All four timers (QPC, `GetTickCount`, `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime`, and `Sleep`) should agree to within measurement error.

Another thing you can do is correlate against an external source. For example, you can write a function which obtains the time from the file system by creating a file and then asking for the file creation time. Correlate this against the other four timers. Other external sources are the sound and video hardware. For example, you can play a 1 second sound clip and see how long it takes. Or wait for the vertical blank and see if it matches the monitor refresh rate.

Comment: This program, Cheat Engine, (that i've been using to change speed of my processes) only changes single process' speed. When i change my own application's speed with it i can see the change with QueryPerformanceCounter but when i do it for another process i can't see the change. So, i need to run QueryPerformanceCounter() in another process and get its return value to my own application.